# .nav-item.hover doesn't change the color of nav-link

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

How can I change the following so that when I hover over a navbar item, its color changes to red?

```
.nav-item.active .nav-link{
    color: blue !important;
}
.nav-item.hover .nav-link{
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: `.hover` --> `:hover` ?

Comment: Thank you. It is interesting that WebStorm also provided me with .hover option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use colon instead of dot before pseudo classes in CSS selector, [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp):

```
.nav-item:active .nav-link{
    color: blue !important;
}
.nav-item:hover .nav-link{
    color: red !important;
}
```

> note **:active** and **:hover**